# Flutter - Aligning Overflowed Children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: MyContainer]

A container with a black background contains an image of a 3 X 3 grid.

The child was allowed to overflow regardless of the size of the container.

What I want to do now is to place the image in the middle of the 3X3 grid (Images in 2 x 2 locations) in the middle of the container.

**CODE**

```
Widget game() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      child: Image.network(
        imgUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
        colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
        width: 200,
        height: 170,
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
Widget games() {
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            game(),
            SizedBox(width: margin),
            game(),
            SizedBox(width: margin),
            game(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      height: 400,
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              games(),
              SizedBox(height: margin),
              games(),
              SizedBox(height: margin),
              games(),
              SizedBox(height: margin),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your main container to be:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ),
    height: 400,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: games()),
        SizedBox(height: margin),
        Expanded(child: games()),
        SizedBox(height: margin),
        Expanded(child: games()),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

and your `games` method to:

```
Widget games() {
  return Wrap(
    direction: Axis.vertical,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: game()),
          SizedBox(width: margin),
          Expanded(child: game()),
          SizedBox(width: margin),
          Expanded(child: game()),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

What `Expanded` does is to take the maximum area available,
so if you had 3 `Expanded`s inside a `Row`, each will take 33.3% of the `Row`'s width, same applied to the `Column`

Ex.:
your main container has a height of `400`, and the column child has 3 `Expanded`s and 2 `SizedBox`es, in that case what actually happens that every Expanded will take height as (400 - (2 * margin)) / 3

Comment: I don't want each element of 3x3 to be scaled to fit the parent container.


Each element wants to be overflowed regardless of the size of the parent.


Therefore, the result is that the image in the 2 X 2 position is in the middle and the rest of the images are truncated.